# Обращение к элементу массива, который является полем структуры из массива структур в Ассемблере (MASM)

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, структуры, masm, x86

У меня есть массив структур, каждая из которых содержит два массива

```
Tabl1 struc
    namex db 4 dup (?)
    field1 dw 4 dup (?)
Tabl1 ENDS

Data1 segment
    I_struc db ?
    I_namex db ?
    A1 Tabl1 6 dup (<>)
Data1 ends
```

Мне нужно инициализировать каждый элемент массива Field1 каждой структуры каким-то значением.

Вопрос: как обратиться к этому элементу используя счетчики I_struc, I_namex из сегмента данных? 
Пока что у меня есть такой код:

```
Code1 segment
    ASSUME cs:Code1, ds:Data1  
begin:
mov bx, 4
mov cx, 6
loop_1:
    imul I_struc, cx, size Tabl1
    loop_2:
        imul I_namex, bx, size dw
        mov byte ptr A1[I_struc-size Tabl1].field1[I_namex - size dw], somevalue ;line 25
    loop loop_2
loop loop_1

mov ax, 4C00H 
int 21H

Code1 ends
    end begin
```

Но компилятор MASM говорит dw symbol is not defined, хотя это и стандартный тип.

[image: Screenshot_1]

Используя 2 вместо size dw (что по сути размер типа dw в байтах) выдает такую ошибку.

[image: Screenshot_2]

Используя "sizeof dw" вместо "size dw" выдает такую ошибку.

[image: Screen_3]

Что я делаю не так и какое может быть этому решение?

Comment: *У меня есть массив структур, каждая из которых содержит два массива* -- это не так.

Comment: @PinkTux что именно не так и почему?

Comment: Я так полагаю должно быть умножение вместо вычитания?

Comment: Сначала опишите, например, на Си, что вы хотите получить, потом попробуйте переписать на ассемблер. Учитывайте, что на ассемблере не получится записать в одну строку все что угодно. Адресовать можно максимум так: `mov [c + ebx + edi*2^N], somevalue` (константа + базовый регистр + индексный регистр с умножением на степень двойки (масштабированием)). Два раза применить масштабирование к разным регистрам в одной строке не получится. Можно заранее посчитать смещение нужного элемента, а потом записать данные по этому смещению.

Comment: @insolor на си мой пример должен выглядеть как while(I_struc < 6){ while(I_namex<4){ A1[I_struc].field1[I_namex] = somevalue; I_namex++;} I_struc++;} В данном случае мне нужно использовать эти же счетчики элементов в ассемблере

Comment: Скорее всего одной командой не получится. Нужно сначала найти смещение начала внутренней структуры, потом относительно этого смещения адресоваться.